# C++ Declaring a 2d array with a size function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to declare a 2d array by using the size() method for STL map:

```
const int size = edge_map.size();//get row and column size

int a[size][size];//nxn matrix
```

I keep getting a compiler error that the size must be a constant value even though I am declaring it as a constant. Is there any work around for this without having to use a dynamic 2d array?

Comment: dynamically allocated arrays must be defined using the `new` keyword.

Comment: @NiVeR i'm not trying to declare it dynamically, i just want to use the size function to get the number and use that number as the dimensions of a 2d array.

Comment: `const int` is not the same as an integer constant, despite the similarity of the names.

Comment: @Daoud if the size of the array is not defined at compile time, then it is by definition dynamic. You're asking how to make an array that can be any size without using the kind of array that can be any size.

Comment: You could use a resizable container like `std::vector`, and translate 2D indexes into 1D indexes; for any `T[rN][cN]`, you would create `vector<T> a(rN * cN)`, which has `rN * cN` elements, and to access element `[r][c]`, you would use `(r * rN) + c` as the index (e.g., for an `int[5][5]`, `vector<int> a(25)`, and for element `[3][1]`, index `16` (`(3 * 5) + 1`)).  This is just an abstraction for a dynamic 1D array, though, with the benefit that you don't need to do the memory management yourself.  Not posting this as an answer, as it may not meet your needs due to still being dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` means to not change its original (initial) value.

But `size` must be known at *compile time*, as the compiler/linker allocates memory for non-local variables (declared out of any function).

Comment: i see, this is my problem. Is there any way you recommend i go about this?

Comment: You have to allocate it in the heap (instead of the stack), i. e. dynamically, so there is no way around, if you don´t know dimensions ranges in advance and insist that it have to be declared out of any function.

Comment: gcc has an extension that allows one dimension to be set without using a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3):

Static memory allocation for arrays can accept variables as long as the value of the variable can be determined at compile-time. The reason for this requirement is because the compiler must know how much memory to allocate for the array on the stack. If `edge_map` is what it sounds like (some kind of container which can change sizes throughout its existence), you are not going to be able to do it this way.

If this is not the case, though, and `edge_map.size()` has a return value which can be determined at compile-time, marking that function as `constexpr` should allow this code to work.

Comment: you are correct, it does change throughout existence,  but is there a way to capture its value at a specific time in the program and use it as a dimension of the 2d array?

Comment: @Daoud Yes... by using the `new` keyword. If you don't use `new`, the compiler needs to know how much memory will be needed at the time of compilation.